# A stop job is running... if I execute dhcpcd and don't kill it on ARCH

Tags: troubleshooting, jobs, dhcpcd

I have recently installed arch. Noticed that when shutting it down often a "A stop job is running for session 3 of root.." message appears which takes 1:30 minutes to dissapear. Further investigation and looking at `journalctl` led me to the conclusion that this happens everytime I run `dhcpcd`. I do this so I can have internet access, first `ip link set something up`and then `dhcpcd`. If I kill `dhcpcd` the system shuts down without problem.

What should I do?

Comment: I installed NetworkManager and don't have problem with that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more detail in your logs. I'd recommend looking at the logs to determine *why* the process is hanging (so long). A look at the termination command might provide some clues. You might compare that with some of the others to get a better idea why DHCPD is hanging, while the others are not.

HTH